# Is pinch for font size changes in tableview ok re usability?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, usability

Is pinch for font size changes in tableview ok re usability?

Seems a good idea from my perspective, but wondering would users find it ok, or does it break an iPhone best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read through the tableView human interface guidelines and didn't see anything explicit there. In the [Direct Manipulation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Principles/Principles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH5-SW3) section it says:

> people can use the pinch gestures to directly expand or contract an area of content

If the user is using a pinch and zoom to change all text in a tableview it doesn't really seem to me like it is really proper "direct manipulation." It seems like it is more of a global setting change with a generic gesture. I think the real decision would come down to why are you planning to offer this gesture to the user? Is there a common use case for your app that the user would want to adjust the font size often? Are they going to change it more than once per session?

I know it is nice to offer lots of features, but any extra features are just going to obfuscate the real features. It may confuse the user if they accidentally do a pinch and then the text size is changed and they don't make the connection.

Overral, I don't think it breaks and explicit rule, but I would be really careful about deciding to add this "feature." If there is a really good reason to do it, I would say go for it, otherwise, it probably isn't worth the risk of getting rejected from the store and/or possibly confusing the user.

Answer (score 1):

I vote no if it's key to the functionality of your app. You're having to train people to do something that may not be intuitive for them to realize that's there.  If you look that the Twitter official app, they do something similar to expand the content in that cell, but you could totally live without that capability if you didn't know it was there.

Comment: thanks - in my case I did have a toolbar with a font increase and decrease icon, so the question was usability re such a feature above and beyond this...I'm guessing it might not change your answer but just for completeness